# What type of design is this experiment? 3x2x2 Factorial design?

Tags: data-analysis, experimental-design

I am running an experiment to find out if the pattern of expected and actual guilt people feel when making and not making a purchase is dependent on proximity to their payday (e.g. do people expect/actually feel more guilt about making than not making a purchase toward the end of the month than at the start or middle, and expect/experience more guilt about not making a purchase toward the beginning of the month than at the middle or end of the month).

Time of the month (early, mid, late) and type of guilt (expected and actual) were both measured between subjects.
The extent to which people feel guilty for making and not making the impulsive purchase was measured within-subjects.

Participants were provided with a story about making a purchase at one of three times of the month (manipulation). They were then asked EITHER to answer questions about the expected OR actual guilt they experienced as a result of both making AND not making the purchase.

All responses were captured using 7 point scales.

Overall, the data obtained leaves me with the following groups for analysis for each of the three times of the month:

1. Expected guilt for making the purchase
2. Expected guilt for not making the purchase
3. Actual guilt for making the purchase
4. Actual guilt for not making the purcahse

I think it may be a 3 (time of month) X 2 (expected guilt) x 2 (actual guilt) factorial design. Does this sound right to answer my question? And would this be analysed using a mixed ANOVA?

Thank you for any help.